# Extract date from string in date format, add n number of days. to then replace with that modified data another substring within the original string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, datetime, regex-group

```py
import re, datetime, time

input_text = "tras la aparicion del objeto misterioso el 2022-12-30 visitamos ese sitio nuevamente revisando detras de los arboles pero recien tras 3 dias ese objeto aparecio de nuevo tras 2 arboles" #example 1
input_text = "luego el 2022-11-15 fuimos nuevamente a dicho lugar pero nada ocurrio y 3 dias despues ese objeto aparecio en el cielo durante el atardecer de aquel dia de verano" #example 2
input_text = "Me entere del misterioso suceso ese 2022-11-01 y el 2022-11-15 fuimos al monte pero nada ocurrio, pero luego de 13 dias ese objeto aparecio en el cielo" #example 3


identified_referencial_date = r"(?P<year>\d*)-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<startDay>\d{2})" #obtained with regex capture groups

# r"(?:luego[\s|]*de[\s|]*unos|luego[\s|]*de|pasados[\s|]*ya[\s|]*unos|pasados[\s|]*unos|pasados[\s|]*ya|pasados|tras[\s|]*ya|tras)[\s|]*\d*[\s|]*(?:días|dias|día|dia)"
# r"\d*[\s|]*(?:días|dias|día|dia)[\s|]*(?:despues|luego)"
n =       #the number of days that in this case should increase

indicated_date_relative_to_another = str(identified_date_in_date_format - datetime.timedelta(days = int(n) ))

input_text = re.sub(identified_referencial_date, indicated_date_relative_to_another, input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

The objective is that if a day is indicated first in the format **year-month-day** (are integers separated by hyphens in that order) `\d*-\d{2}-\d{2}` and then it says that n amount of days have passed, so you would have to replace that sentence with **year-month-day+n**

`luego de unos 3 dias` ---> add 3 days to a previous date

`luego de 6 dias` ---> add 6 days to a previous date

`pasados ya 13 dias` ---> add 13 days to a previous date

`pasados ya unos 48 dias` ---> add 48 days to a previous date

`pasados unos 36 dias`  ---> add 36 days to a previous date

`pasados 9 dias`  ---> add 9 days to a previous date

`tras ya 2 dias`  ---> add 2 days to a previous date

`tras 32 dias`  ---> add 32 days to a previous date

`3 dias despues`  ---> add 3 days to a previous date

`3 dias luego`  ---> add 3 days to a previous date

Keep in mind that in certain cases, increasing the number of days could also change the number of the month or even the year, as in example 1.

**Outputs** that I need obtain in each case:

```
"tras la aparicion del objeto misterioso el 2022-12-30 visitamos ese sitio nuevamente revisando detras de los arboles pero recien 2023-01-02 ese objeto aparecio de nuevo tras 2 arboles" #for the example 1

"luego el 2022-11-15 fuimos nuevamente a dicho lugar pero nada ocurrio y 2022-11-18 ese objeto aparecio en el cielo durante el atardecer de aquel dia de verano" #for the example 2

"Me entere del misterioso suceso ese 2022-11-01 y el 2022-11-15 fuimos al monte pero nada ocurrio, pero 2022-11-28 ese objeto aparecio en el cielo" #for the example 3
```

Comment: In the outputs section, I don't see anything has changed in examples 2 and 3.

Comment: @trincot Ohhh I'm really sorry, you're right by accident when I was setting up the question I pressed ctr-z and forgot to put the outputs correctly. Anyway I fixed it there. Now, as in example 1, in example 2 and 3 it can be seen that the indication of n following days changes to a specific date

Comment: I think you changed the original date of the first example. Did you want to update the input?

Comment: @trincot I always kept the input the same, the only thing I added was what you told me, that is, I adapted the output of example 2 and 3, of 1 do not modify anything. In example 1 "2022-12-30" + 3 days = "2023-01-02" , in the example 2 "2022-11-15" + 3 days =  2022-11-18 , and in the example 3 "2022-11-15" + 13 days = "2022-11-28"

Comment: Yes, but at the top of your question you don't have "2022-12-30" in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex solution you could use:

```
([12]\d{3}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d)(\D*?)(?:(?:luego de|pasados|tras)(?: ya)?(?: unos)? (\d+) dias|(\d+) dias (?:despues|luego))
```

This regex requires that there are no other digits between the date and the days. It also is a bit loose on grammar. It would also match "luego de ya 3 dias". You can of course make it more precise with a longer regex, but you get the picture.

In a program:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re

def add(datestr, days):
    return (datetime.strptime(datestr, "%Y-%m-%d") 
            + timedelta(days=int(days))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

input_texts = [
    "tras la aparicion del objeto misterioso el 2022-12-30 visitamos ese sitio nuevamente revisando detras de los arboles pero recien tras 3 dias ese objeto aparecio de nuevo tras 2 arboles",
    "luego el 2022-11-15 fuimos nuevamente a dicho lugar pero nada ocurrio y 3 dias despues ese objeto aparecio en el cielo durante el atardecer de aquel dia de verano",
    "Me entere del misterioso suceso ese 2022-11-01 y el 2022-11-15 fuimos al monte pero nada ocurrio, pero luego de 13 dias ese objeto aparecio en el cielo"
]

for input_text in input_texts:
    result = re.sub(r"([12]\d{3}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d)(\D*?)(?:(?:luego de|pasados|tras)(?: ya)?(?: unos)? (\d+) dias|(\d+) dias (?:despues|luego))",
                    lambda m: m[1] + m[2] + add(m[1], m[3] or m[4]), 
                    input_text)
    print(result)
```